# Check for convergence/divergence $\Sigma_1^\infty{\frac{\arctan(n)}{n^3}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\Sigma_1^\infty{\frac{\arctan(n)}{n^3}}$

I tried to find the limit of $\frac{\arctan(n)}{n^3}$ and got to 3. But I'm missing something, because simply finding a limit to $a_n$ doesn't cut it.

Comment: Recall that $|\arctan x|<\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then use the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^p}$ converges for all $p>1$.

Comment: As Frank Lu noted, proving this converges is easy. Much harder is $\sum_1^\infty{\frac{\tan(n)}{n^p}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series converges. Indeed $${\frac{arctan(n)}{n^3}}\sim_{\infty}{\frac{\pi/2}{n^3}}$$ But $ \frac{1}{n^3}$
converges

Comment: I have used your answer with the comparison test. Thank you.